# Search Plugin, searches across languages

Tags: plugins, impresspages

I have tried the new text search plugin, I know this is still under development, but perhaps this will help.

1. First comment is that the plugin has to be inserted into the page, whereas the search plugin in 3.x was coded into the template so that it appeared in all pages.
2. I am working with a 2 language site PL/EN.  When doing a text search in on the PL side the search plugin finds the word on the EN side and gives a link to the page on the EN side.  When I click on the link on the PL side I get a 404 message.

If I repeat the search (same word) on the EN side,  the the search plugin finds the word, gives the link on the EN side (same link as given in the PL side) and when I click on this link I get the correct page.

So it appears that the plugin searches the whole site but cannot complete links when the text is on the other  language side on the site.

Comment: Thanks. Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. To display a search box, place the following PHP code to your theme layout file:

   echo ipSlot('searchBox');
2. I've just added some multilanguage support. Please get the latest version from Git. :)

Thanks for your feedback!

Cheers.

Marijus

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I can get the search box to where I want on the page, but I cannot find any way to control the size of the search box.  Will this come as the plugin is developed ?